# Power BI - JSON file formatting doesn't work

Tags: powerbi

I have created the following test report by Power BI Desktop with one Card visual.

[image]

I saved this formatting into the JSON file (View => Themes => Save current theme) because I want that the same formatting to be used in dashboard also. In Power BI cloud service I uploaded the same JSON file but nothing happens to the Card formatting. It still looks the same gray. Why is that?

[image]

The content of JSON file is as following:

[image]

Is it because the JSON file doesn't contain references to the Card visual? But if I saved the report's theme that contained the Card visual then why didn't it build complete JSON file that could contain all report elements? How can I know what is the right reference tag for each elements. Microsoft doesn't seem to have appropriate manual also.

Comment: You will need to reference the card visual, as you are changing the data colours on the charts not the text. I would recommend using a theme builder like https://powerbi.tips/tools/report-theme-generator-v3/

Comment: I constructed the JSON file using the Report Theme Generator. The content of JSON file looks like this:  
{
 "name":"card_theme",
 "visualStyles":{"*":{"*":{"*":[{"color":{"solid":{}}}]}},
 "card":{"*":{"labels":[{"show":true,"color":{"solid":{"color":"#7A2B2E"}},
 "labelPrecision":1,
 "fontSize":18,
 "fontFamily":"Arial Black"}]}}}
}
I uploaded this theme to Power BI service but nothing changed in dashboard. The Card visual looks still the same - plain and unformatted. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The JSON indicates that it is the label being updated, not the value text. It might be a limitation of the themes

Comment: So, why there are Dashboards in Power BI at all if in reality we can't use them - the default styling is awful and the modification of this so painful (if not to say impossible)?